# How to Detect Swipe Gestures on iOS Devices using Unity?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I am working on a Unity project that requires the implementation of swipe gestures for iOS devices. However I have encountered an issue with the built in Unity Input Manager.

It appears that it is not able to detect swipes. I am aware that iOS devices have their own built in swipe detection capabilities.

Is there a way to access this functionality through Unitys' C# scripting system? Additionally I appreciate any guidance regarding third party libraries or plugins that could assist me in integrating swipe detection into my Unity project.

I have attempted to create my own custom swipe detection algorithm but it was not successful. Consequently. I am uncertain about the best approach for establishing a reliable swipe detection system for iOS devices. I'm a newcomer to both Unity and iOS development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an asset like this: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/easy-swipe-touch-controller-31255

Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).